# Ember.js How to observe selection changes with view Ember.Select multiple=true?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, observers

I've tried to observe selection change for simple Ember.Select and it works, but when I use select with multiple=true it fails. Here some code:

```
 {{view Ember.Select
 multiple=true
 contentBinding="App.TopicController"
 selectionBinding="content.TOPICS"
 optionLabelPath="content.label"
 optionValuePath="content.id"}}
```

When I change selection on my input it must trigger observer:

```
App.Configuration = Em.Object.extend({
    TOPICS:[],

  // this observer must work when selection changes
  topicsSelected: function() {
    console.log('topics selection changed!');
  }.observes('TOPICS', 'TOPICS.@each', 'TOPICS.length')

});
```

JSBin with this problem: [http://jsbin.com/](http://jsbin.com/ofONeQ/10/edit?html,js,console,output)

**Versions**: handlebars 1.0.0, ember 1.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the `TOPICS` variable to `topics` will solve this problem. I think this happen because this problem https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/3098.

In your `topicsSelected` observer if you want to observe the selection just `observes('topics.length')` is needed.

Give a look in your updated jsbin http://jsbin.com/ofONeQ/14/edit

Comment: `observes('topics.length')` is not enough. If one item is selected and the user selects another item then the length will not change. Just `observes('topics.@each')` works fine though.